# HashMap и его внутренности

Tags: java

> `HashMap` - структура данных для хранения связанных вместе пар
>   "ключ-значение", применяется для использования хеш-таблицы. Был
>   специально разработан для быстрого доступа к элементам.

Как понять для использования хэш-таблицы?

Comment: ну грубо говоря, hashMap это обёртка над устаревшей Hashtable (это не совсем правда, но для понимания мне кажется подойдёт лучше).

Comment: Непонятно, что вам непонятно. [Хэш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) - это структура данных, а `HashMap` - это класс, реализующий эту структуру.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev если грубо говоря HashMap реализация, а Хэш-таблица абстракция?)

Comment: @MikeMclaren нет. `Map` - это абстракция, а хэш-таблица - это конкретный тип данных.